# Spring Auth Server JwtGenerator casts token setting settings.token.access-token-format of type LinkedHashMap to OAuth2TokenFormat

Tags: spring-security, spring-authorization-server

`Spring Boot 3.1.1`

`spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server 1.1.1`

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to class org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.settings.OAuth2TokenFormat (java.util.LinkedHashMap is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.settings.OAuth2TokenFormat is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.settings.TokenSettings.getAccessTokenFormat(TokenSettings.java:66) ~[spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server-1.1.1.jar:1.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.token.JwtGenerator.generate(JwtGenerator.java:83) ~[spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server-1.1.1.jar:1.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.token.JwtGenerator.generate(JwtGenerator.java:60) ~[spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server-1.1.1.jar:1.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.authentication.OAuth2ClientCredentialsAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(OAuth2ClientCredentialsAuthenticationProvider.java:125) ~[spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server-1.1.1.jar:1.1.1]
```

Don't know if i'm excluding some funky new functionality somewhere....?
I've never known this to be a feature so please correct me.

[Class OAuth2TokenFormat](https://docs.spring.io/spring-authorization-server/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/oauth2/server/authorization/settings/OAuth2TokenFormat.html)

```
OAuth2TokenFormat(String value)
```

[image]

The RegisteredClient is created using the JPA example from the documentation.

[Auth Server JPA example](https://docs.spring.io/spring-authorization-server/docs/current/reference/html/guides/how-to-jpa.html#create-jpa-entities)

```
private RegisteredClient toRegisteredClient(RegisteredClientEntity registeredClientEntity) {
        
        Set<String> clientAuthenticationMethods = StringUtils.commaDelimitedListToSet(
            registeredClientEntity.getClientAuthenticationMethods());
        Set<String> authorizationGrantTypes = StringUtils.commaDelimitedListToSet(
            registeredClientEntity.getAuthorizationGrantTypes());
        Set<String> redirectUris = StringUtils.commaDelimitedListToSet(
            registeredClientEntity.getRedirectUris());
        Set<String> postLogoutRedirectUris = StringUtils.commaDelimitedListToSet(
            registeredClientEntity.getPostLogoutRedirectUris());
        Set<String> clientScopes = StringUtils.commaDelimitedListToSet(
            registeredClientEntity.getScopes());
        
        RegisteredClient.Builder builder =
            RegisteredClient
                .withId(registeredClientEntity.getId())
                .clientId(registeredClientEntity.getClientId())
                .clientIdIssuedAt(registeredClientEntity.getClientIdIssuedAt())
                .clientSecret(registeredClientEntity.getClientSecret())
                .clientSecretExpiresAt(registeredClientEntity.getClientSecretExpiresAt())
                .clientName(registeredClientEntity.getClientName())
                .clientAuthenticationMethods(
                    authenticationMethods ->
                        clientAuthenticationMethods
                            .forEach(authenticationMethod ->
                                authenticationMethods.add(resolveClientAuthenticationMethod(authenticationMethod))))
                .authorizationGrantTypes(grantTypes ->
                    authorizationGrantTypes
                        .forEach(grantType -> grantTypes.add(resolveAuthorizationGrantType(grantType))))
                .redirectUris(uris -> uris.addAll(redirectUris))
                .postLogoutRedirectUris(uris -> uris.addAll(postLogoutRedirectUris))
                .scopes(scopes -> scopes.addAll(clientScopes));
        
        Map<String, Object> clientSettingsMap = 
            MappingUtils.jsonStringToMap(objectMapper, registeredClientEntity.getClientSettings());
        
        builder.clientSettings(ClientSettings.withSettings(clientSettingsMap).build());
        
        Map<String, Object> tokenSettingsMap =
            MappingUtils.jsonStringToMap(objectMapper, registeredClientEntity.getTokenSettings());
        
        builder.tokenSettings(TokenSettings.withSettings(tokenSettingsMap).build());
        
        return builder.build();
    }
```

A test to prove the point as well as the output:

```
package co.mytest.authserver;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.JavaTimeModule;
import lombok.SneakyThrows;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.settings.OAuth2TokenFormat;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.settings.TokenSettings;

import java.util.Map;

public class TokenSettingsTest {
    
    @SneakyThrows
    @Test
    void test(){
    
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
        
        TokenSettings tokenSettings = TokenSettings.builder().build();
        String tokenSettingsJson = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(tokenSettings.getSettings());
        
        System.out.println(tokenSettings);
        
        Map<String, Object> tokenSettingsMap =
            objectMapper.readValue(
                tokenSettingsJson, new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>(){});
    
        TokenSettings deserializedTokenSettings = TokenSettings.withSettings(tokenSettingsMap).build();
        OAuth2TokenFormat oAuth2TokenFormat = deserializedTokenSettings.getAccessTokenFormat();
        System.out.println("TokenSettings created");
    }
    
    //AbstractSettings {settings={settings.token.reuse-refresh-tokens=true, settings.token.id-token-signature-algorithm=RS256, settings.token.access-token-time-to-live=PT5M, settings.token.access-token-format=org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.settings.OAuth2TokenFormat@face4f32, settings.token.refresh-token-time-to-live=PT1H, settings.token.authorization-code-time-to-live=PT5M, settings.token.device-code-time-to-live=PT5M}}
    //
    //java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to class org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.settings.OAuth2TokenFormat (java.util.LinkedHashMap is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.settings.OAuth2TokenFormat is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    //
    //  at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.settings.TokenSettings.getAccessTokenFormat(TokenSettings.java:66)
    
}
```

Thanks @SteveRiesenberg!
**This is going to trip up many people i suspect.**

My initial suspicions confirmed - there is some funky functionality you need to summon.

The ObjectMapper needs preperation:

```
        ClassLoader classLoader = AuthServerApplication.class.getClassLoader();
        List<Module> securityModules = SecurityJackson2Modules.getModules(classLoader);
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.registerModules(securityModules);
        objectMapper.registerModule(new OAuth2AuthorizationServerJackson2Module());
```

Carefull when creating a Jackson customizer:

```
@Bean
    public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer jsonCustomizer() {
        
        ClassLoader classLoader = ValiantAuthServerApplication.class.getClassLoader();
        List<Module> securityModules = SecurityJackson2Modules.getModules(classLoader);
        securityModules.add(new OAuth2AuthorizationServerJackson2Module());
    
        // The modules AbstractList passed to the consumer doesn't support add()??? Workaround. 
        return jacksonObjectMapperBuilder -> {
            jacksonObjectMapperBuilder.modulesToInstall(securityModules::addAll);
            jacksonObjectMapperBuilder.modulesToInstall(securityModules.toArray(new Module[0]));
        };
    }
```

Comment: It looks like your `RegisteredClient` was created (possibly deserialized from json?) with a bad value. How was the registered client created and/or loaded?

Comment: @SteveRiesenberg , thanks for responding. I added the source to my question.

Comment: I just ran a test with the code from the guide that sets the `tokenFormat` to `REFERENCE` and does a save/find operation on the `JpaRegisteredClientRepository`. I cannot reproduce your issue. Please post all relevant code, as it appears something is different in your setup. I'm particularly interested in how you initialize and use the `objectMapper` and how you create the `RegisteredClient` instance before it is saved? I'm also wondering if you upgraded recently?

Comment: @SteveRiesenberg - i added a test case based on the extracts from the JPA example.

Comment: Thanks for the extra details. Unfortunately, you are not initializing `ObjectMapper` correctly. See the constructor of `JpaRegisteredClientRepository` in the guide.

Comment: @SteveRiesenberg - Thanks! I created a bean for that but never applied it to the mapper: ` @Bean
    public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer jsonCustomizer() ` - Will give it a go.

Answer (score 0):

The ObjectMapper needs special preperation. (See the original question)

I had a bug in the Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer which caused the required modules not to load.
Be carefull with the customizer/builder. I ran into some unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The `token_settings` in `oauth2_registered_client` need the correct syntax for the token format:

```
"settings.token.access-token-format":{"@class":"org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.settings.OAuth2TokenFormat","value":"self-contained"}
```